# Insert text with hyperlink in Gmail with Google Script?

Tags: email, google-apps-script, attachment

I am trying to send an email with an attachment and the URL of the attachment. The email body would look like this:

"Hi Everyone-

Here's the [agenda](http://google.com) for tomorrow's meeting.

See you in the morning!

-John Doe"

I have written the code to my best ability. I know I wrote the bottom half erroneously. Please assist.

```
  function sendEmailTest() {
  //test send email.
  // Send an email with an attachment: a file from Google Drive.
    var file = DocumentApp.openById(file2.getId());
    var ssUrl = 'URL_BUFFERED';
    var sheetName = 'Sheet1';   // name of sheet to use
    var rangeName = 'C30';    // range of values to include 
    var dateRange = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(ssUrl)
       .getSheetByName(sheetName)
       .getRange(rangeName)
       .getValues();

  // Name of Google file to attach.
    var file2 = file.makeCopy('Weekly Agenda | '+dateRange);

  // Set Agenda URL.
    var theBody = GmailApp.openById(file2.getId()).getBody();
    var elementReplaced = theBody.replaceText("%toReplace%", "agendaURL");
    elementReplaced.asText().setLinkUrl("https://google.com");

  //Send email.
        MailApp.sendEmail('who@whowantstoknow.com', file2, 'Hi Everyone- \n Here\'s the ' +agendaURL+'agenda for tomorrow
                   's meeting. \n See you in the morning! \n-John Doe', {
        name: 'Automatic Emailer Script',
        attachments: [file.getAs(file2)] });
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found that sending out emails using GAS is suggested to do so in HTML. zaq just posted his answer right after I found a better way to re-write my code. Thank you zaq though! Here is my working code:

```
    var emailTo = 'totheuniverse@omnipresence.com';
    var subject = "Weekly Agenda | " +dateRange;
    var options = {}
    options.htmlBody = "Hi Everyone-" +'<br />'+'<br />'+ "Here\'s the " + '<a href=\"' +agendaURL+ '">agenda</a>' + " for tomorrow\
's meeting." +'<br />'+'<br />'+ "See you in the morning!" +'<br />'+'<br />'+ "-John Doe";
    options.attachment = [file];
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailTo, subject, '', options);
```

Answer (score 8):

Inserting a hyperlink in email requires sending the email in HTML, rather than in plain text as you do now. Change the syntax of sendEmail call to [`sendEmail(Object)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendEmail(Object)) where the argument is an object with htmlBody field containing your message. Like this:

```
var message = {
  to: "recipient@example.com",
  subject: "Weekly Agenda | " + dateRange,
  htmlBody: "Hi Everyone-\n Here's the <a href='" + agendaURL + ''">agenda</a> for tomorrow's meeting.\n See you in the morning!\n-John Doe", 
  name: "Automatic Emailer Script",
  attachments: [file2.getAs(MimeType.PDF)]
};
MailApp.sendEmail(message);
```

Using double quotes for message body is preferable, because then you don't need to escape apostrophes in text.

Answer (score 0):

I have put the message body directly on my sheet and I have used the below code adapting the above logic. Sharing with all who find it useful,

```
<a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YHIwETgynFw&feature=youtu.be">click here</a>
```